# Visual Studio Online Continuous Integration Angular2

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create angular2 CI on VS Online. 
I added command line to build process and trying to run ng build command from angular-cli.
I am using self hosted agent and angular-cli is installed on the machine.
I also used same agent to build asp.net core so I know that my agent is working.

Cmd:

```
ng build
```

Error

> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: Is it part of the `PATH` environment variable? Are you specifying a working folder that points to the location of `ng`? Either of those should solve the issue.

Comment: machine didnt use the same angular cli as my client so that was an issue and laso after i updated angular-cli your answer helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel said that:

You can add the ng location to system variable:

1. System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variable
2. Click New button to add system variable (variable name: ng variable value: ng local location) > OK
3. Select Path variable > Edit
4. Append ;%ng” to the value of path variable
5. Restart machine

You also can specify full path of ng to **Tool** value of **Command Line** step/task, then specify Working folder with your angular2 project path.